# Fix a seed in R using NLMR package

Tags: r, r-raster, random-seed

I'm using the [NLMR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLMR/index.html) package with

```
# simulate polygonal landscapes
mosaicgibbs <- NLMR::nlm_mosaicgibbs(ncol = 100,
                               nrow = 100,
                               germs = 20,
                               R = 2,
                               patch_classes = 3)
# visualize the NLM
rasterVis::levelplot(mosaicgibbs, margin = FALSE, par.settings = rasterVis::viridisTheme())
```

But I would like to fix the seed number in order to reproduce the spatial pattern .

I have tried with `set.seed(123)` but it doesn't work.
E.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this helps in your case, but I couldn't just make a comment. In `nlm_gaussianfield()` the syntax for setting the seed is:

> nlm_gaussianfield(nrow=10, ncol= 10, user_seed = 123)

The default is `NULL`. Maybe this works in `nlm_mosaicgibbs()` as well. Good luck!